# Does running 2 Linux shell commands with & make them start at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My end goal is to start 2 commands at the same time (or at least a few hundred ms delta from each other). I read about `&` in Linux. For ex:

`<linux_shell_cmd_1> & <linux_shell_cmd_2>`

Would this achieve my goal? Thanks.

Comment: It will achieve that. however, cmd1 will run in background while cmd2 will run in foreground

Comment: The second command will be started *as soon as possible* after the first one is started. How soon that is, though, is up to the OS scheduler. Your script might be suspended for an arbitrary amount of time (to allow other jobs CPU time) before it resumes to start the second job.

Answer (score 2):

Given as your goal is to be within a few hundred ms delta, this should work as-needed on typical modern hardware under a reasonable quantity of load.

```
cmd1 & cmd2     # start cmd1 in background and cmd2 in foreground
```

...starts `cmd1` in the background (without waiting for it to finish), and then starts `cmd2` in the foreground.

You might also consider:

```
cmd1 & cmd2 &   # start both cmd1 and cmd2 in background
```

---

In either case, *the process of starting the first* is started very slightly before the process of starting the second, but there's no guarantee as to any ordering beyond that (if it takes longer to invoke `cmd1` than `cmd2`, then the latter may actually be first to start up).